# Default zone of Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, high-availability, iaas, availability-zone

While deploying a VM in Azure. If I choose a region ex. "Central India" which is having support of Availability zone, but I am not choosing that option while deploying. Then what will be the default zone in which the VM get deployed?

I think it will be zone 1, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment got results like below***:

I deployed virtual machine and I choose region as ***Central India*** by default it's support of ***Availability zone as zone 1*** without selecting an option of zone like below:

[image]

To confirm in portal, once vm deployed it supported as zone 1 like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure Availability Zones – vegibit](https://vegibit.com/azure-availability-zones/)